# Where should i place the packages?

Tags: java, development-environment, package

I got the source code for differentiation(from numericalmethods.com). The code imported certain packages. So I downloaded these packages(suanshu packages) but I don't know where these packages should be placed because the program imports these packages. The packages are of the form com.numericalmethod.suanshu.algebra.linear.vector.doubles.Vector;

Comment: I believe they should go in com/numericalmethod/suanshu/algebra/linear/vector/doubles, which is horrible

Comment: Everything depends on what file type you have for the package and build tool you are using. If you are talking about java source, the files should be placed together with your source in a directory matching the package name. If you are talking about a jar, in a lib directory. Please clarify

Comment: just paste the outermost folder inside your src

Comment: @richard, should i place them in C:\ drive ?

Comment: /..../somefilestructure/your project/com/numericalmethod/.....

Answer (score 0):

Download the jars of those packages and add them to your classpath. If you are using Eclipse IDE, then add the jar to the projects java build path.

Comment: I am using editplus. I have downloaded them. could you please elaborate ? I don't know much about classpath. I'm a beginner to java

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `.jar` file with needed packages and classes to the classpath of your application.

From [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html):

> The preferred way to specify the class path is by using the -cp command line switch. This allows the CLASSPATH to be set individually for each application without affecting other applications.

For example, `java -cp ".;suanshu.jar" MainClass` for Windows environment.
Now you can treat classes and packages in `.jar` as if they were in the location of your application.
In the code, you import classes as `import com.numericalmethod.<etc>.Vector;` and your program looks for them in `com/numericalmethod/<etc>/Vector.class` inside the suanshu.jar archive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the jar manually in your project.
Modern Java project uses Maven. They have a maven repo that you can have the dependencies downloaded automatically.

NM Repository

```
<repository>
    <id>nm-repo</id>
    <name>NM Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.nm.dev/maven/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

To use NM Dev, in the  section, add:

NM Dev dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.nm</groupId>
    <artifactId>nmdev</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See this for reference:
https://nm.dev